# concatenation string search in solr

Tags: java, solr

I am searching for medical related terms.

Search fields are

```
description, title, keywords, category.
```

Search key by user

```
"brain surgery"
```

When I search with the above key, it searches all four of the mentioned fields as per the schema. The problem is this: The indexed items may contain many records with the key `"surgery"` in say the description. My search results in items related to `cardiology, knee` etc because it has the keyword `"surgery"` in the description.

I only want one record which has `"brain surgery"` in the description. How can I achieve this?

FYI: while sending, I send the key as `"brain+surgery"`

Any help is appreciated

### SOLRCONFIG.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<config>

  <luceneMatchVersion>LUCENE_42</luceneMatchVersion>


  <lib dir="../../../contrib/extraction/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-cell-\d.*\.jar" />

  <lib dir="../../../contrib/clustering/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-clustering-\d.*\.jar" />

  <lib dir="../../../contrib/langid/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-langid-\d.*\.jar" />

  <lib dir="../../../contrib/velocity/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-velocity-\d.*\.jar" />

  <lib dir="/total/crap/dir/ignored" /> 


  <directoryFactory name="DirectoryFactory" 
                    class="${solr.directoryFactory:solr.NRTCachingDirectoryFactory}"/> 

  <codecFactory class="solr.SchemaCodecFactory"/>


  <indexConfig>

    <lockType>${solr.lock.type:native}</lockType>


  </indexConfig>



  <jmx />

  <updateHandler class="solr.DirectUpdateHandler2">


    <updateLog>
      <str name="dir">${solr.ulog.dir:}</str>
    </updateLog>


     <autoCommit> 
       <maxTime>15000</maxTime> 
       <openSearcher>false</openSearcher> 
     </autoCommit>



  </updateHandler>


  <query>

    <maxBooleanClauses>1024</maxBooleanClauses>


    <filterCache class="solr.FastLRUCache"
                 size="512"
                 initialSize="512"
                 autowarmCount="0"/>


    <queryResultCache class="solr.LRUCache"
                     size="512"
                     initialSize="512"
                     autowarmCount="0"/>


    <documentCache class="solr.LRUCache"
                   size="512"
                   initialSize="512"
                   autowarmCount="0"/>


    <enableLazyFieldLoading>true</enableLazyFieldLoading>


   <queryResultWindowSize>20</queryResultWindowSize>


   <queryResultMaxDocsCached>200</queryResultMaxDocsCached>


    <listener event="newSearcher" class="solr.QuerySenderListener">
      <arr name="queries">

      </arr>
    </listener>
    <listener event="firstSearcher" class="solr.QuerySenderListener">
      <arr name="queries">
        <lst>
          <str name="q">static firstSearcher warming in solrconfig.xml</str>
        </lst>
      </arr>
    </listener>


    <useColdSearcher>false</useColdSearcher>


    <maxWarmingSearchers>2</maxWarmingSearchers>

  </query>


  <requestDispatcher handleSelect="false" >

    <requestParsers enableRemoteStreaming="true" 
                    multipartUploadLimitInKB="2048000"
                    formdataUploadLimitInKB="2048"/>


    <httpCaching never304="true" />

  </requestDispatcher>


  <requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">

     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
       <int name="rows">10</int>
       <str name="df">all_fields</str>
     </lst>

    </requestHandler>

  <!-- A request handler that returns indented JSON by default -->
  <requestHandler name="/query" class="solr.SearchHandler">
     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
       <str name="wt">json</str>
       <str name="indent">true</str>
       <str name="df">all_fields</str>
     </lst>
  </requestHandler>


  <requestHandler name="/get" class="solr.RealTimeGetHandler">
     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="omitHeader">true</str>
       <str name="wt">json</str>
       <str name="indent">true</str>
     </lst>
  </requestHandler>

  <requestHandler name="/browse" class="solr.SearchHandler">
     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>

       <!-- VelocityResponseWriter settings -->
       <str name="wt">velocity</str>
       <str name="v.template">browse</str>
       <str name="v.layout">layout</str>
       <str name="title">Solritas</str>

       <!-- Query settings -->
       <str name="defType">edismax</str>
       <str name="qf">
          text^0.5 features^1.0 name^1.2 sku^1.5 id^10.0 manu^1.1 cat^1.4
          title^10.0 description^5.0 keywords^5.0 author^2.0 resourcename^1.0
       </str>
       <str name="df">all_fields</str>
       <str name="mm">100%</str>
       <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
       <str name="rows">10</str>
       <str name="fl">*,score</str>

       <str name="mlt.qf">
         text^0.5 features^1.0 name^1.2 sku^1.5 id^10.0 manu^1.1 cat^1.4
         title^10.0 description^5.0 keywords^5.0 author^2.0 resourcename^1.0
       </str>
       <str name="mlt.fl">text,features,name,sku,id,manu,cat,title,description,keywords,author,resourcename</str>
       <int name="mlt.count">3</int>

       <!-- Faceting defaults -->
       <str name="facet">on</str>
       <str name="facet.field">cat</str>
       <str name="facet.field">manu_exact</str>
       <str name="facet.field">content_type</str>
       <str name="facet.field">author_s</str>
       <str name="facet.query">ipod</str>
       <str name="facet.query">GB</str>
       <str name="facet.mincount">1</str>
       <str name="facet.pivot">cat,inStock</str>
       <str name="facet.range.other">after</str>
       <str name="facet.range">price</str>
       <int name="f.price.facet.range.start">0</int>
       <int name="f.price.facet.range.end">600</int>
       <int name="f.price.facet.range.gap">50</int>
       <str name="facet.range">popularity</str>
       <int name="f.popularity.facet.range.start">0</int>
       <int name="f.popularity.facet.range.end">10</int>
       <int name="f.popularity.facet.range.gap">3</int>
       <str name="facet.range">manufacturedate_dt</str>
       <str name="f.manufacturedate_dt.facet.range.start">NOW/YEAR-10YEARS</str>
       <str name="f.manufacturedate_dt.facet.range.end">NOW</str>
       <str name="f.manufacturedate_dt.facet.range.gap">+1YEAR</str>
       <str name="f.manufacturedate_dt.facet.range.other">before</str>
       <str name="f.manufacturedate_dt.facet.range.other">after</str>

       <!-- Highlighting defaults -->
       <str name="hl">on</str>
       <str name="hl.fl">content features title name</str>
       <str name="hl.encoder">html</str>
       <str name="hl.simple.pre">&lt;b&gt;</str>
       <str name="hl.simple.post">&lt;/b&gt;</str>
       <str name="f.title.hl.fragsize">0</str>
       <str name="f.title.hl.alternateField">title</str>
       <str name="f.name.hl.fragsize">0</str>
       <str name="f.name.hl.alternateField">name</str>
       <str name="f.content.hl.snippets">3</str>
       <str name="f.content.hl.fragsize">200</str>
       <str name="f.content.hl.alternateField">content</str>
       <str name="f.content.hl.maxAlternateFieldLength">750</str>

       <!-- Spell checking defaults -->
       <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
       <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">false</str>       
       <str name="spellcheck.count">5</str>
       <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">2</str>
       <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">5</str>       
       <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
       <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str>  
       <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">5</str>
       <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">3</str>           
     </lst>

     <!-- append spellchecking to our list of components -->
     <arr name="last-components">
       <str>spellcheck</str>
     </arr>
  </requestHandler>

  <requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler">

  </requestHandler>

  <!-- for back compat with clients using /update/json and /update/csv -->  
  <requestHandler name="/update/json" class="solr.JsonUpdateRequestHandler">
        <lst name="defaults">
         <str name="stream.contentType">application/json</str>
       </lst>
  </requestHandler>
  <requestHandler name="/update/csv" class="solr.CSVRequestHandler">
        <lst name="defaults">
         <str name="stream.contentType">application/csv</str>
       </lst>
  </requestHandler>

  <!-- Solr Cell Update Request Handler

       http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler 

    -->
  <requestHandler name="/update/extract" 
                  startup="lazy"
                  class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler" >
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="lowernames">true</str>
      <str name="uprefix">ignored_</str>

      <!-- capture link hrefs but ignore div attributes -->
      <str name="captureAttr">true</str>
      <str name="fmap.a">links</str>
      <str name="fmap.div">ignored_</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>


  <requestHandler name="/analysis/field" 
                  startup="lazy"
                  class="solr.FieldAnalysisRequestHandler" />


  <requestHandler name="/analysis/document" 
                  class="solr.DocumentAnalysisRequestHandler" 
                  startup="lazy" />


  <requestHandler name="/admin/" 
                  class="solr.admin.AdminHandlers" />

  <requestHandler name="/admin/ping" class="solr.PingRequestHandler">
    <lst name="invariants">
      <str name="q">solrpingquery</str>
    </lst>
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">all</str>
    </lst>

  </requestHandler>

  <!-- Echo the request contents back to the client -->
  <requestHandler name="/debug/dump" class="solr.DumpRequestHandler" >
    <lst name="defaults">
     <str name="echoParams">explicit</str> 
     <str name="echoHandler">true</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>


  <requestHandler name="/replication" class="solr.ReplicationHandler" > 

  </requestHandler>


  <searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">

    <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">textSpell</str>


    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">default</str>
      <str name="field">name</str>
      <str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>
      <!-- the spellcheck distance measure used, the default is the internal levenshtein -->
      <str name="distanceMeasure">internal</str>
      <!-- minimum accuracy needed to be considered a valid spellcheck suggestion -->
      <float name="accuracy">0.5</float>
      <!-- the maximum #edits we consider when enumerating terms: can be 1 or 2 -->
      <int name="maxEdits">2</int>
      <!-- the minimum shared prefix when enumerating terms -->
      <int name="minPrefix">1</int>
      <!-- maximum number of inspections per result. -->
      <int name="maxInspections">5</int>
      <!-- minimum length of a query term to be considered for correction -->
      <int name="minQueryLength">4</int>
      <!-- maximum threshold of documents a query term can appear to be considered for correction -->
      <float name="maxQueryFrequency">0.01</float>
      <!-- uncomment this to require suggestions to occur in 1% of the documents
        <float name="thresholdTokenFrequency">.01</float>
      -->
    </lst>

    <!-- a spellchecker that can break or combine words.  See "/spell" handler below for usage -->
    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">wordbreak</str>
      <str name="classname">solr.WordBreakSolrSpellChecker</str>      
      <str name="field">name</str>
      <str name="combineWords">true</str>
      <str name="breakWords">true</str>
      <int name="maxChanges">10</int>
    </lst>


  </searchComponent>


  <requestHandler name="/spell" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="df">all_fields</str>
      <!-- Solr will use suggestions from both the 'default' spellchecker
           and from the 'wordbreak' spellchecker and combine them.
           collations (re-written queries) can include a combination of
           corrections from both spellcheckers -->
      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">wordbreak</str>
      <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>       
      <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">5</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">5</str>       
      <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str>  
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">10</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">5</str>         
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>


  <searchComponent name="tvComponent" class="solr.TermVectorComponent"/>


  <requestHandler name="/tvrh" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="df">all_fields</str>
      <bool name="tv">true</bool>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>tvComponent</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>


  <searchComponent name="clustering"
                   enable="${solr.clustering.enabled:false}"
                   class="solr.clustering.ClusteringComponent" >
    <!-- Declare an engine -->
    <lst name="engine">
      <!-- The name, only one can be named "default" -->
      <str name="name">default</str>


      <str name="carrot.algorithm">org.carrot2.clustering.lingo.LingoClusteringAlgorithm</str>


      <str name="LingoClusteringAlgorithm.desiredClusterCountBase">20</str>


      <str name="carrot.lexicalResourcesDir">clustering/carrot2</str>


      <str name="MultilingualClustering.defaultLanguage">ENGLISH</str>
    </lst>
    <lst name="engine">
      <str name="name">stc</str>
      <str name="carrot.algorithm">org.carrot2.clustering.stc.STCClusteringAlgorithm</str>
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>


  <requestHandler name="/clustering"
                  startup="lazy"
                  enable="${solr.clustering.enabled:false}"
                  class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <bool name="clustering">true</bool>
      <str name="clustering.engine">default</str>
      <bool name="clustering.results">true</bool>
      <!-- The title field -->
      <str name="carrot.title">name</str>
      <str name="carrot.url">id</str>
      <!-- The field to cluster on -->
       <str name="carrot.snippet">features</str>
       <!-- produce summaries -->
       <bool name="carrot.produceSummary">true</bool>
       <!-- the maximum number of labels per cluster -->
       <!--<int name="carrot.numDescriptions">5</int>-->
       <!-- produce sub clusters -->
       <bool name="carrot.outputSubClusters">false</bool>

       <str name="defType">edismax</str>
       <str name="qf">
         text^0.5 features^1.0 name^1.2 sku^1.5 id^10.0 manu^1.1 cat^1.4
       </str>
       <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
       <str name="rows">10</str>
       <str name="fl">*,score</str>
    </lst>     
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>clustering</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>


  <searchComponent name="terms" class="solr.TermsComponent"/>

  <!-- A request handler for demonstrating the terms component -->
  <requestHandler name="/terms" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
     <lst name="defaults">
      <bool name="terms">true</bool>
      <bool name="distrib">false</bool>
    </lst>     
    <arr name="components">
      <str>terms</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>


  <searchComponent name="elevator" class="solr.QueryElevationComponent" >
    <!-- pick a fieldType to analyze queries -->
    <str name="queryFieldType">string</str>
    <str name="config-file">elevate.xml</str>
  </searchComponent>

  <!-- A request handler for demonstrating the elevator component -->
  <requestHandler name="/elevate" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
      <str name="df">all_fields</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>elevator</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>

  <!-- Highlighting Component

       http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters
    -->
  <searchComponent class="solr.HighlightComponent" name="highlight">
    <highlighting>
      <!-- Configure the standard fragmenter -->
      <!-- This could most likely be commented out in the "default" case -->
      <fragmenter name="gap" 
                  default="true"
                  class="solr.highlight.GapFragmenter">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <int name="hl.fragsize">100</int>
        </lst>
      </fragmenter>

      <!-- A regular-expression-based fragmenter 
           (for sentence extraction) 
        -->
      <fragmenter name="regex" 
                  class="solr.highlight.RegexFragmenter">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <!-- slightly smaller fragsizes work better because of slop -->
          <int name="hl.fragsize">70</int>
          <!-- allow 50% slop on fragment sizes -->
          <float name="hl.regex.slop">0.5</float>
          <!-- a basic sentence pattern -->
          <str name="hl.regex.pattern">[-\w ,/\n\&quot;&apos;]{20,200}</str>
        </lst>
      </fragmenter>

      <!-- Configure the standard formatter -->
      <formatter name="html" 
                 default="true"
                 class="solr.highlight.HtmlFormatter">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="hl.simple.pre"><![CDATA[<em>]]></str>
          <str name="hl.simple.post"><![CDATA[</em>]]></str>
        </lst>
      </formatter>

      <!-- Configure the standard encoder -->
      <encoder name="html" 
               class="solr.highlight.HtmlEncoder" />

      <!-- Configure the standard fragListBuilder -->
      <fragListBuilder name="simple" 
                       class="solr.highlight.SimpleFragListBuilder"/>

      <!-- Configure the single fragListBuilder -->
      <fragListBuilder name="single" 
                       class="solr.highlight.SingleFragListBuilder"/>

      <!-- Configure the weighted fragListBuilder -->
      <fragListBuilder name="weighted" 
                       default="true"
                       class="solr.highlight.WeightedFragListBuilder"/>

      <!-- default tag FragmentsBuilder -->
      <fragmentsBuilder name="default" 
                        default="true"
                        class="solr.highlight.ScoreOrderFragmentsBuilder">

      </fragmentsBuilder>
      <!-- multi-colored tag FragmentsBuilder -->
      <fragmentsBuilder name="colored" 
                        class="solr.highlight.ScoreOrderFragmentsBuilder">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="hl.tag.pre"><![CDATA[
               <b style="background:yellow">,<b style="background:lawgreen">,
               <b style="background:aquamarine">,<b style="background:magenta">,
               <b style="background:palegreen">,<b style="background:coral">,
               <b style="background:wheat">,<b style="background:khaki">,
               <b style="background:lime">,<b style="background:deepskyblue">]]></str>
          <str name="hl.tag.post"><![CDATA[</b>]]></str>
        </lst>
      </fragmentsBuilder>  
      <boundaryScanner name="default" 
                       default="true"
                       class="solr.highlight.SimpleBoundaryScanner">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="hl.bs.maxScan">10</str>
          <str name="hl.bs.chars">.,!? &#9;&#10;&#13;</str>
        </lst>
      </boundaryScanner>

      <boundaryScanner name="breakIterator" 
                       class="solr.highlight.BreakIteratorBoundaryScanner">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <!-- type should be one of CHARACTER, WORD(default), LINE and SENTENCE -->
          <str name="hl.bs.type">WORD</str>
          <!-- language and country are used when constructing Locale object.  -->
          <!-- And the Locale object will be used when getting instance of BreakIterator -->
          <str name="hl.bs.language">en</str>
          <str name="hl.bs.country">US</str>
        </lst>
      </boundaryScanner>
    </highlighting>
  </searchComponent>
  <queryResponseWriter name="json" class="solr.JSONResponseWriter">
     <!-- For the purposes of the tutorial, JSON responses are written as
      plain text so that they are easy to read in *any* browser.
      If you expect a MIME type of "application/json" just remove this override.
     -->
    <str name="content-type">text/plain; charset=UTF-8</str>
  </queryResponseWriter>

  <!--
     Custom response writers can be declared as needed...
    -->
    <queryResponseWriter name="velocity" class="solr.VelocityResponseWriter" startup="lazy"/>


  <!-- XSLT response writer transforms the XML output by any xslt file found
       in Solr's conf/xslt directory.  Changes to xslt files are checked for
       every xsltCacheLifetimeSeconds.  
    -->
  <queryResponseWriter name="xslt" class="solr.XSLTResponseWriter">
    <int name="xsltCacheLifetimeSeconds">5</int>
  </queryResponseWriter>
  <admin>
    <defaultQuery>*:*</defaultQuery>
  </admin>

</config>
```

Comment: what are your configuration for search ? is it a phase query ? you seems to be using query to match few search terms rather then all due to which the results are returning

Comment: http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=all_fields:brain+surgery. I am unsure on that phase query. I pass as above

Comment: what request handler are you using ? can you post your solrconfig.xml ?

Comment: i have added the xml...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using the default search handler which seems to have the OR as the [default query operator](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Default_query_parser_operator).
You can check using `q=all_fields:brain+surgery&q.op=AND` which will set the query operator to AND and would make all the query terms as mandatory.

Comment: i have one minor issue while searching in a multivalued field. checkout the difference in multivalued field ex 1 : abc, xyz, lmn...........ex 2 : abc,xyz,lmn. You can notice the space after comma. if i search for xyz. sometimes it works for ex1 sometimes for ex2. Is this a concern here ?????

Comment: space would create tokens while no space between terms might not create tokens (depending upon analysis performed) ... so search would differ

Comment: so its better to give space while indexing ?

Comment: yup or split to data and index them as multivalued fields so that they appear as array.

Comment: Hi jayendra, i was referring to one of your links regarding sorting. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970666/how-to-sort-by-date-in-solr/12970779#12970779 i tried that and it is not working. Is there any setting i need to make in XML ?

Comment: Sorting does not work on text fields.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991885/solr-wrong-sort-text-fields/7992380#7992380. If its not the case please provide more details.

Comment: nope i want to sort based on type="date" desc. What are the other possible types allowed ?

Comment: date is supported out of box so just check if the field is indexed.

Comment: yes, i deleted all & added again ensuring it is indexed in prior. my query is ?q=all_fields:xyz&wt=json&q.op=AND&sort=timestamp and i am getting error as "Can't determine a Sort Order (asc or desc) in sort spec 'timestamp', pos=9" tried appending desc OR asc after timestamp..fails to load

Comment: indexed time stamps... 2013-05-09T06:19:01.032Z, 2013-05-09T06:20:37.482Z, 2013-05-09T06:20:04.907Z, 2013-05-09T06:17:55.827Z

Comment: the parameter must be sort=timestamp desc. desc or asc should be always applied with the sort parameter. there is no default.

Comment: tried with that too....results are not showing up... is my query proper ?q=all_fields:xyz&wt=json&q.op=AND&sort=timestamp desc

Comment: please provide with more details for the field type fields and data indexed.

Comment: <field name="timestamp" type="date" indexed="true" 
    stored="true" required="true" default="NOW"/> and data indexed as 2013-05-09T06:19:01.032Z

Comment: are results showing up without sort ? what sort behavior are you getting ?

Comment: hey its working now. i added like this sort=timestamp+desc. I guess space was the concern. Thought initially to be syntax of giving space.... thanks very much for the support